# Probability of Getting 3 aces in 13 cards

Tags: probability

There are 52 cards in a poker card set. If the cards are being given to 4 players, W, X, Y, and Z. Each of them will get 13 cards. What is the probability of a player Y getting exactly 3 aces?

Initially, I get the probability using
$$
P=\frac{4}{52}\times\frac{3}{51}\times\frac{2}{50}=\frac{1}{5525}
$$

I tried using the other way

$$
P =\frac{{{13}\choose{1}} {{12}\choose{10}}{{4}\choose{3}} {{4}\choose{1}}^{10}}{{52}\choose{13}} = 5.667 \times10^{-3}
$$

Can someone please explain to me why these 2 ways have different probabilities and which way is the most direct way to tackle this kind of situation?

Comment: Is it a specific player or at least one of the players?

Comment: Edited. One of the players, for example, player Y

Comment: Just to be clear, one of the players and one specific player refers to the same thing right?

Comment: In the distribution, is there an idea of order : like W gets his card before the others ?

Comment: @MachineLearner75 there is no idea of order.

Comment: What are you representing with the combinaison (12, 10) ? You select 10 cards out of the 12 remaining categories ?

Comment: @MachineLearner75 (12, 10) is the 10 remaining cards from 12 available ranks

Comment: Do you mean exactly three aces or at least three aces?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig exactly 3 aces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player $Y$ can receive $13$ cards in
$$\binom{52}{13}$$
ways.  For player $Y$ to receive exactly three aces, player $Y$ must receives three of the four aces and $10$ of the remaining $48$ cards in the deck.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{10}$$
Therefore, the probability that player $Y$ receives exactly three aces is
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{48}{10}}{\dbinom{52}{13}}$$

---

You have calculated the probabilities of other events.

Your first approach is the probability that three aces are selected when three cards are selected from the deck.  Your second approach gives the probability that three cards of one rank are selected and one card each is drawn from ten of the other twelve ranks.  If you wanted to find the probability that three aces are selected and one card each is drawn from ten of the other twelve ranks, you would drop the factor of $13$ since there is only one way to choose the rank ace.